winget wont upgrade on Windows 11
I need to upgrade winget onto new fresh Windows 11 23H2 installations (already fully updated).
I have tried manual GUI installation clicking on the .msixbundle file downloaded from https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli but it doesn't succeed, with no clear informations/suggestions about.
I then tried to open a PowerShell session with admin privileges and run winget upgrade MicrosoftAppInstaller. The CLI returns to me error 0x8a15000f : Data required by the source is missing
I would like to upgrade the default Win11 versione 1.17.10691.0 to the latest one

Lost the output of winget source list and verify you can reach the entry label as winget within a browser. After doing so try running winget source update. If that still doesn’t work I have other ideas

Are you trying to upgrade Winget, or MicrosoftAppInstaller? Is this a business computer owned by your employer, or a personal device?

According to Ramhound suggestions the issue seems to be solved.
winget source list returns
Nome    Argomento                                     Contenuti espliciti
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
msstore https://storeedgefd.dsx.mp.microsoft.com/v9.0 false
winget  https://cdn.winget.microsoft.com/cache        false

but the content of winget xml file returns:
<Error>
<Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
<Message>The specified resource does not exist. RequestId:e4fa72b3-101e-004d-564e-196f85000000 Time:2024-10-08T06:52:36.9634238Z</Message>
</Error>

Then, after running winget source update, I finally got the latest version 1.23.1911.0
Please Note: the issue I have reported does not occur on fresh Windows 10 22H2 installations (already fully updated). Why is there such different behaviour between Win10 and Win11?

Such solution seems to work fine also on 24H2 build

The answer I posted recently works in most cases. I tried on other more recent machines where I installed Windows 11 in the same way. In these cases the solution does not work.
The problem seems to be due to a failed update of the winget repositories (I delete the comment to my previous answer in order to expand the issue herein). I tried to follow the workaround proposed here
Still on some test machines this patch works, on few others it does not.
In terms of reproducibility on all the test machines (Intel i5 from the 6th to the 12th generation) I installed the same Windows 11 23H2 iso image. On all the test machines I did all the possible updates proposed by Windows Update.
I have no further clues about till now...
